# If window.location.href does not match a certain string, add css class to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to javascript/jQuery and am trying to add a css class to an element if the page's url **does not match** one of three strings.  I cannot these lines of my code to work.

```
  if (window.location.href.match(/(interests|ideas|art)/) > -1) {
    jQuery("#nav-about").addClass('active');
  }
```

Any ideas? Is my syntax incorrect?

**EDIT:**

It seems like the answers everyone has given me should be working, but they aren't.  Maybe other lines of my code are conflicting:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.location.href.search(/(interests|ideas|art)/) > -1) {
      jQuery("#nav-about").addClass('active');
  }
  if (window.location.href.match(/(interests)/) != null) {
    jQuery("#nav-interests").addClass('active');
  }
  if (window.location.href.match(/(ideas)/) != null) {
    jQuery("#nav-ideas").addClass('active');
  }
  if (window.location.href.match(/(art)/) != null) {
    jQuery("#nav-art").addClass('active');
  }
});
```

My site is [benxd.me](http://benxd.me). The link, `#nav-about` on this main page is what needs the class `active`; the script does not work on this page.  The script on the other pages, interests, ideas and photography work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you are doing, you want to use [`.search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) not [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). The return value for `.search()` is the index of the first match, or `-1` if there is not a match.  The return value for [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is:

> An [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) containing the entire match result and any parentheses-captured matched results; [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) if there were no matches.

Fixing the above issue, and given that you have stated you want to add the class when the URL does *not* match, the code should be:

```
if (window.location.href.search(/(interests|ideas|art)/) === -1) {
    jQuery("#nav-about").addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: @moped, Yes.  That will also work, but, potentially, results in a bit more processing given that `.match()` will search the entire string, not stopping at the first matching position, and returns an array with more information (if a match is found).

Answer (score 1):

You can use string.search or string.indexOf method in js. Here is an example code.

```
var url = 'http://localhost:3000/interests';
var url1 = 'http://localhost:3000/ideas';

if (url.search('interests') > -1) {
  // do your work
}
```

or

```
if (url1.indexOf('ideas') > -1) {
  // do your work
}
```

Here is your fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/Refatrafi/grxpmaon/3/

Answer (score 1):

I use the following function to perform the same basic procedure.

```
function NavSetActiveLink() {
    var currentLocation = window.location.pathname;
    $(".nav-element a").each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('href') === currentLocation){
            $(this).addClass('active');
            return false; // break out of the loop
        }
    });
}
```

The function cycles through each `.nav-element a` and finds the first `<a>` with an href that matches the current `window.location.pathname`, assuming relative links.

As long as your nav elements have an `<a>` tag directly related to each one, i.e. a parent or child or self, you can make this work.